# Random Forest Cp is 0

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, boosting

I am trying to run a randomforest model for price prediction, and when I run tuneGrid in randomforest, I found that the bestTune cp is 0.00, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand yes, it is possible, though I'm not sure as to why. Sorry, I couldn't write this as a comment, not enough reputation.

Comment: Thank you, when I rescale the step, it showed 0.001 as the best cp, would furthuer rescale be helpful?

Comment: If the accuracy is not going to improve any further with a cp of .001 then I don't think that rescaling would be necessary?